# How a checkbox can be added to the search form in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

As a newbie to Drupal 8, I get an assignment to hide the additional checkbox field, based on some condition, that has been added under the search textfield on the `/search`page.

I have spent hours to look for the code how additional field can be added to the Drupal 8 search form, but I could not find it.

Can someone give me some clue where to look at? In case, additional field can be added via the administrator interface, which page is it? In case, additional field can be added via a custom module, which `hook` function might have been implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to find a field name ('reset' in the example below):

[image]

Then look for such string in code (try $form['reset'], ['reset'], 'reset' with single or double quotes until you find it). Replace all hyphens with underscores, if any:

[image]

Most likely you will end up with [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.6.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.6.x).

[What are Drupal hooks](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/what-are-hooks?p=2766).